# Docker does not identify npm install command and throws error

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

My **Dockerfile** is as shown below:

```
From ubuntu:14.04

WORKDIR /app

#COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY . /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Now, when I run command `sudo docker -t my-app .`. It gives me the following error:

> Sending build context to Docker daemon 453.6 kB Sending build context
>   to Docker daemon Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:14.04  ---> 37a9c4a8276c Step 1
>   : WORKDIR /app  ---> Using cache  ---> a83d4ef27948 Step 2 : COPY .
>   /app  ---> 1029f5d7d8a3 Removing intermediate container eb9e7ea7f7e6
>   Step 3 : RUN npm install  ---> Running in 5d4f2c05d2d8 /bin/sh: 1:
>   npm: not found INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c npm install]
>   returned a non-zero code: 127

Is there anything missing in my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. Your image doesn't have node installed, since the base image is ubuntu. You should use the [node](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/node/) image as a base image.

```
From node

WORKDIR /app

#COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY . /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile is building vanilla ubuntu `FROM ubuntu:14.04` so if you want to use npm/node in your container you'll need to setup node yourself by adding `RUN` commands to install node, following the install [instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) for ubuntu.

**Instead of this, you probably want to simply use the official node image found at:**

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

`FROM node`

or use a specific version/distro like

`FROM node:8.4.0-wheezy`

(other tags/versions/distros are listed on the docker hub page)